# globalVars In less file

Tags: javascript, variables, less, inline

I'm wondering if there is any chance to get all the defined variables inside escaped less javascript code.

e.g.

```
@allvars: `(function(){ return globalVars;})()`;
```

its urgents for a project I'm working on.
Just for the record, I just need the already defined ones.
**Not** all variables in all files.

Thanks for the help

Comment: In short, no, in the inline javascript you don't have access to any defined stuff except those things you explicitly pass in with `"@{var}`. I suppose your goal is achievable by writing a [visitor plugin](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1861#issuecomment-58464947) but I'm afraid there's no specific docs about this stuff I can point you to (the only docs so far is the compiler source code itself).

Comment: meh thats sad, is there any chance to import a file via mixins? I guess the imports are only working with static names..

Comment: Yes, it's valid to import a file inside a mixin. E.g. `.mixin(@name) {@import "../foo/@{name}.less";}` is fine. (Note though that interpolation of mixin's local variables inside imports is valid only since Less v2).

Answer (score 0):

Im doing it that way now

```
 .theme(@theme) {&{.compile(@theme);}}
```

usage: 
     .theme(main) // will compile all mixins in .compile() for given theme

inside the compiler mixin I do this

```
.compile(@theme) {&{
        @base-color: 'theme-@{theme}-base-color';
        .another-module(@@base-color);
 }}
```

In that way I have seperated the compiling proccess completely form the assigning of themes. works like charm here.
Sure it's a lot of typing to reassign all the colors, but god bless multiedit.
And you just do it once for each module so who cares after all.

Hope this helps someone else

Comment: That's why eventually I hope we'll get rid of that global variables madness (considered harmful in mainstream languages since about 1960s) and start to use more generic things like namespaces, value lists and so on. (Some work to be done at the Less side to be done before that though). Though for your particular example I can't quite follow why you need those `theme-theme_name-base-color` variables at all. You can define variables with humane names in a mixin and invoke it wherever you need those ([like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/0a7bb650ab0ca2d27049) for example).

Comment: because if you want to override or even use them in later theming, you cant. This way i have unique identifiers and can handle stuff differently.

Comment: >because if you want to override or even use them in later theming, you cant - You [can](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/05d2d4ca8f007a617e72) actually.

Comment: So what would be if i wanted to use a var form super-flat in an custom less file? You **cant** access it without overriding all the defaults. Except you make a guard expression and pass a returner to a second variable, which would be a hassle to use for production

Comment: Hmm, I guess I can understand what you mean though it still sound strange - e.g. you design a multi-theme CSS and then you make another piece of CSS to refer to a specific theme value (e.g. "here's a CSS class and it always has"pink" background) - that way it looks like this should be done in reverse - e.g. for that "piece of CSS" you define you `@always-pink` stuff and then in your theme definitions art you refer to that variabels from within a "pink" theme.

Comment: But well, never mind, I guess we're quickly sinking to a very specific cases and every rule has its excetion.  My rule is `if-your-variables-have-to-look-like-this` it's definitely something wrong with the approach itself. But if you made it that way probably you had enough reasons.

Comment: true true, thing is that i want to add some styles afterwards, if i can't acces colors thats even worse than having long variable names ;)

Comment: Actually i can remove the "@theme-" because those variable names a relativly stirct. So a it would look something like this. `@main-base-color:   transparent; `